# Can I remove all break lines except the first and last one from jwt key

Tags: node.js, security, encryption, openssl, jwt

I generated jwt key (RSA Key: private and public) using the following commands

```
openssl genrsa -out private.key 2048
openssl rsa -in private.key -pubout -out public.key
```

After that, I created a file called `private2.key`, I gave it the same `private.key` content (the only difference is that I removed all break lines except the first and last one)

Also, I created a file called `public2.key`, I gave it the same `public.key` content (the only difference is that I removed all break lines except the first and last one)

**private.key**:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

**private2.key**:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEowIBAAKCAQEAy6fZ1JmG4BX02R2Odj/zso7hJwq7qsTZs6SVcNdiHeDxCRT5UQvTO/qxSIips89iyDTahPjFaquTvmF+oTTOXqA80SYtE8JK2r2/QJ9te5je/7jB8yxrRsp5heZ4uQv9yThygvOTItuHDN+w4Le2QReegunRDnbfTrsogwUmVAyam4qFiBDx3zEoTp98H4lRYB4Mpekt0Z2fh8q4g1vBaJLSc+Vc8MXLXsuQTNZ0x61fV7p93ewJAHlSxNYRdEFuhNMjU7hp2DR6zQqqyEWslFyq0JW6pd7hHjuCSoBcW5e4lrEgZgLspbWbl0rlIOQFizy+IJumXKDmM90WHp2v9wIDAQABAoIBAQDDiSmw4qeJSAuK2sIJ72VAr8amAbwmPlL4FLIXYfUm0u8a1TR8CGqMUCsfhXfK2PfzWivlOCX0QUDdriYzCcyLNjauaYUmT4onc7/JgElSPnj99prhrGhj08vSMHMA2O6W4Mexy8Qd18FXLv9ZA4rN/KuI7o524NOPeEtxYORoFOslq02PBBuPxTToRs2f++px1HOkLQBt+MknLqh/gK+0w4CD3JDc/yM2jH4z8jZw8E33vmMGdj59mjhsVlgvOine0mvZnJRU9BWSsgdtHwnbBIuQBkiXaMWgY83rrP/hSCCcCcKUNyUgxtlWwMcSZrM/gkt2tts7EkRDe8evVvMhAoGBAO0leVSvjQ8NVqNQajV+o6Z58j2WVTOFG4qZWhuQA4O0oNT4Gcf4w+DYLQKntmwQ9ShWciw/f0nJCTknCSo0TVmIl5yhJVtudWlIosMw6YerpK7VW+6xJ53ZkHn+6EGgBEYuJjHXFw+vY3VnOmsqO3yCON2oUtw2RA1/tLkiJqZzAoGBANvYwa5e8dHpdqVKQX1YZFkA1O8y20lDNgGZNz/8qiY21kmMiVAXsTK9wWiF7Uys/jp0btwWY3u/MHpzP/zz0OTcOJ5b9u+NVcSYzF6FrUGGpOrb9Oh124x2UCKL9exsz8xJav4PGfof8uhPGxRSav+DqbmrY+jqVuz1Dn3YnqttAoGAJPPF6DBCpqnJakFJi3RkQ7iUyov2UsTW+c3TgJ/8LDWlKgpO2h4lR4/n05YWkthBmzt9Ju/uAa1VxpYSk4T62Iy0My/ZBlo76V/sHMYuXXmde7C7VoI8ThhsrtXNkwxAHj9qrDF74nHN6algLPqzsj8IZWGpJ689A21217I+m4kCgYA21VdpgHDcJFjdXSn8c4GD2XtCtfKP0V21BFwNb52YrnDAI3dULLSbrUyCH3VSfItkVQoZhtQFV2hmAjzhgIaHro3IobNziFLuGBZRNRJDl6umkHoDSPIblJ7kHviVoYYqs90lxOp7wmA5pRFh/jSFyncYwjDHNTu9Glok9VSN+QKBgDdjjMY41JU21fv2FWvKCwHXJwRSFVT8HNlMC0H9k6x2SZAmhNBtfIlUxY5I5Cnsmkvw2zNxhS2conLAElKqoVSUprv6BvjW+p80dXisctfMTpv/2YM/o0FsIu1ySS+kMK9OAb2kqz9uL38srfN5zdp3FNLrMaE4uRBei8y51D1/
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

**public.key**:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAy6fZ1JmG4BX02R2Odj/z
so7hJwq7qsTZs6SVcNdiHeDxCRT5UQvTO/qxSIips89iyDTahPjFaquTvmF+oTTO
XqA80SYtE8JK2r2/QJ9te5je/7jB8yxrRsp5heZ4uQv9yThygvOTItuHDN+w4Le2
QReegunRDnbfTrsogwUmVAyam4qFiBDx3zEoTp98H4lRYB4Mpekt0Z2fh8q4g1vB
aJLSc+Vc8MXLXsuQTNZ0x61fV7p93ewJAHlSxNYRdEFuhNMjU7hp2DR6zQqqyEWs
lFyq0JW6pd7hHjuCSoBcW5e4lrEgZgLspbWbl0rlIOQFizy+IJumXKDmM90WHp2v
9wIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

**public2.key**:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAy6fZ1JmG4BX02R2Odj/zso7hJwq7qsTZs6SVcNdiHeDxCRT5UQvTO/qxSIips89iyDTahPjFaquTvmF+oTTOXqA80SYtE8JK2r2/QJ9te5je/7jB8yxrRsp5heZ4uQv9yThygvOTItuHDN+w4Le2QReegunRDnbfTrsogwUmVAyam4qFiBDx3zEoTp98H4lRYB4Mpekt0Z2fh8q4g1vBaJLSc+Vc8MXLXsuQTNZ0x61fV7p93ewJAHlSxNYRdEFuhNMjU7hp2DR6zQqqyEWslFyq0JW6pd7hHjuCSoBcW5e4lrEgZgLspbWbl0rlIOQFizy+IJumXKDmM90WHp2v9wIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

When I generated jwt using `private.key` or `private2.key` and I verified it using `public.key` or `public2.key` I got a successful result

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

const privateKey = fs.readFileSync('./private.key');
const publicKey = fs.readFileSync('./public.key');
const privateKey2 = fs.readFileSync('./private2.key');
const publicKey2 = fs.readFileSync('./public2.key');

const token = jwt.sign({foo: 'bar'}, privateKey, {algorithm: 'RS256'});
console.log(jwt.verify(token, publicKey)); // RESULT IS: { foo: 'bar', iat: 1580192807 }
console.log(jwt.verify(token, publicKey2)); // RESULT IS: { foo: 'bar', iat: 1580192807 }

const token2 = jwt.sign({foo: 'bar'}, privateKey2, {algorithm: 'RS256'});
console.log(jwt.verify(token2, publicKey)); // RESULT IS: { foo: 'bar', iat: 1580192807 }
console.log(jwt.verify(token2, publicKey2)); // RESULT IS: { foo: 'bar', iat: 1580192807 }
```

My question is: **Scientifically is "remove all break lines except the first and last one from jwt key (RSA Key: private and public)" does not affect the jwt, is this way safe (please provide references that prove your answer)**

---

So I can do this (with comfortable feel)

**.env**

```
JWT_PRIVATE_KEY=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
JWT_PUBLIC_KEY=MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAy6fZ1JmG4BX02R2Odj/zso7hJwq7qsTZs6SVcNdiHeDxCRT5UQvTO/qxSIips89iyDTahPjFaquTvmF+oTTOXqA80SYtE8JK2r2/QJ9te5je/7jB8yxrRsp5heZ4uQv9yThygvOTItuHDN+w4Le2QReegunRDnbfTrsogwUmVAyam4qFiBDx3zEoTp98H4lRYB4Mpekt0Z2fh8q4g1vBaJLSc+Vc8MXLXsuQTNZ0x61fV7p93ewJAHlSxNYRdEFuhNMjU7hp2DR6zQqqyEWslFyq0JW6pd7hHjuCSoBcW5e4lrEgZgLspbWbl0rlIOQFizy+IJumXKDmM90WHp2v9wIDAQAB
```

**index.js**

```js
require('dotenv').config();
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

const privateKey = `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n${process.env.JWT_PRIVATE_KEY}\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`;
const publicKey = `-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n${process.env.JWT_PUBLIC_KEY}\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----`;

const token = jwt.sign({foo: 'bar'}, privateKey, {algorithm: 'RS256'});
console.log(jwt.verify(token, publicKey)); // RESULT IS: { foo: 'bar', iat: 1580192822 }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## It depends.

Theoretically, the answer is **no** - you can't *always* remove the line breaks.  This is simply because [RFC 1421](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1421) defines situations in which you must include the line breaks:

> Text lines, delimited by the character pair `<CR><LF>`, must be no more than 1000 characters long.

The above statement is in [Section 4.3 of RFC 1421](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1421#section-4.3), the document where the PEM format is defined.

Practically, however, the answer is generally **yes**:  a number of common implementations are quite lenient when parsing objects in PEM format and allow for excessively long text lengths.  Specifically, OpenSSL and the Golang PEM implementation allow this (or, at least lengths longer than 1000 characters).

Try running this command on one of your certificates with the line breaks removed - it succeeds:

```
openssl x509 -text -noout -in certificate.crt
```

**What should you do?**

Don't concern yourself with this problem and instead store your certificates external to your application.  They should be configuration values and stored externally from your application.  Even better, delegate this problem to a technology that is designed to deal with it - Azure has [Key Vault](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/key-vault/), AWS has [Certificate Manager](https://aws.amazon.com/certificate-manager/) and [KMS](https://aws.amazon.com/kms/).

Comment: Could you tell me how I can deal with this problem if I am going to deploy my app to ubuntu on digitalocean

Comment: @AmjedOmar Which problem exactly?  Why can't you just leave them in their PEM files and load them at start up?

Comment: Because it will be visible to others when I will push code to git host

Comment: @AmjedOmar These are _configuration_ values - they shouldn't be in Git.  This is part of your deployment pipeline - it's not related to code.  This is why I recommended use of AWS Certificate Manager or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

I tried doing exactly the same what the OP did by stripping all line breaks:

```
cat private.key | tr -d '\n'
```

And then manually removing the header and footer lines. Although the OP reported that they were successful in using `jsonwebtoken` that way, as of now that no longer seems to be possible:

```
node_modules/jsonwebtoken/sign.js:124
      return failure(new Error((`secretOrPrivateKey must be an asymmetric key when using ${header.alg}`)))
                     ^

Error: secretOrPrivateKey must be an asymmetric key when using RS256
```

So the accepted answer makes even more sense now.